# How to view data between two dates in vb.net using the datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim dfrom As DateTime
    Dim dto As DateTime
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter

    dfrom = dtpicker1.Text
    dto = dtpicker2.Text

    cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=JMI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student_system;User Id=ian;Password=rockstar"
    cn.Open()
    Dim str As String
    Format(dtpicker1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd")
    Format(dtpicker2.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd")
    str = "select Exam_Date from class1  where Exam_Date= '" & dtpicker1.Text & "' and Exam_Date='" & dtpicker2.Text & "'"

    da = New SqlDataAdapter(str, cn)
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt


End Sub
```

i am trying to view data between two dates using the datetimepicker and when i try to run this code i get an error aying "  Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." if anyone can show me how its done, i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your date range in your SQL statment

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim dfrom As DateTime = dtpicker1.Value
Dim dto As DateTime = dtpicker2.Value


cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=JMI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student_system;User Id=ian;Password=rockstar"
cn.Open()
Dim str As String = "select Exam_Date from class1  where Exam_Date >= '" & Format(dFrom, "MM-dd-yyyy") & "' and Exam_Date <='" & Format(dto, "MM-dd-yyyy") & "'"

Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(str, cn)
da.Fill(dt)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

End Sub

Comment: I think it's nicer to use BETWEEN when getting a date range, what do you think? e.g. SELECT Exam_Date FROM class1 where Exam_Date BETWEEN x AND y. Also, your code seems to cause the error 'Value' is not a member of 'Date, remove the value bit